# Safe way to have globally accessible JWT token in Django

Tags: python, django, jwt

There's a lot out there on how to issue JWT tokens to clients *from* Django, but I'm looking for a way to store a JWT token that is issued *to* the Django app for authentication against an external API.

The setup:

1. Django requests and receives token from external API.  It is good for 24 hours.
2. Every time a client a makes a request, the app must make an authenticated call to the external API.  Ideally, if 3 clients make 2 requests each, we should only need to request a single JWT.
3. 24 hours later, a fourth client makes a request.  Django sees that the token is invalid and requests a new one.

The problems here:

1. Requests from multiple clients should not each require their own token.
2. The token must be able to be changed (this rules out sticking it in the settings)
3. The token must be stored securely.

Ideas so far:

1. Stick in the database with a field listing the expiry time. This seems questionable from a security standpoint.
2. Implement some kind of in memory storage like this https://github.com/waveaccounting/dj-inmemorystorage . This seems like overkill.

Any suggestions as to a better way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, looks like the Django cache might solve this as in https://github.com/auth0/auth0-python/issues/56 . I didn't realize Django came with its own bundled, low level cache.  I'll mark it solved if this turns out to be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [django cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/) was the way to go.  See the above link for an example.